# Where to put PHP script for order form?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, dreamweaver

Hi guys I use dreamweaver and I've been following this tutorial. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/projects/article.php/3530691

It's not very specific with the details on where to put the PHP script so i'm confused if I should put it on the same page or in a different page. I have orfm.php which includes the order form and javascript for the calculation.That works fine. After clicking the submit button the action for that leads to submitted.html. But after adding the PHP script on the same page,orfm.php, for inserting data in mysql, it's not working how it should be. Should I put it on a separate page or am I wrong with the placement on the same page?

here's the script:

```
<?
 //uncomment for debugging
 //print_r($_POST);

 //most sites have magic quotes on
 //but if they do not, this code simulates magic quotes
 if( !get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
  {
     if( is_array($_POST) )
       $_POST = array_map('addslashes', $_POST);
  }


  //make sure there is data in the name and email fields
     if( empty($_POST["Name"]) )
  {
   $error["name"] = "Name is required.";
   $Name = "";
  }
  else
  $Name = $_POST["Name"];

  if( empty($_POST["Email"]) )
   {
     $error["email"] = "Email is required.";
     $Email = "";
   }
   else
     $Email = $_POST["Email"];

  if( empty($_POST["OtherInfo"]) )
   {
    $OtherInfo = "";
   }
  else
    $OtherInfo = $_POST["OtherInfo"];

  //check to make sure the qty fields are whole numbers
  //but only check if there was data entered
  if( !empty($_POST["qtyA"]) )
   {
    if( is_numeric($_POST["qtyA"]) && ( intval($_POST["qtyA"]) == floatval($_POST["qtyA"]) ) )
   {
    //we have a whole number
   }
   else
    $error["qtyA"] = "Please enter a whole number for Class A Widgets.";
   }

    if( !empty($_POST["qtyB"]) )
   {
    if( is_numeric($_POST["qtyB"]) && ( intval($_POST["qtyB"]) == floatval($_POST["qtyB"]) ) )
   {
    //we have a whole number
   }
    else
    $error["qtyB"] = "Please enter a whole number for Class B Widgets.";
   }

   if( !empty($_POST["qtyC"]) )
   {
   if( is_numeric($_POST["qtyC"]) && ( intval($_POST["qtyC"]) == floatval($_POST["qtyC"]) ) )
   {
    //we have a whole number
   }
    else
      $error["qtyC"] = "Please enter a whole number for Class C Widgets.";
   }


   //we should have at least 1 item ordered in the form
    if( empty($_POST["qtyA"]) && empty($_POST["qtyB"]) && empty($_POST["qtyC"]) )
    $error["no_qty"] = "Please enter at least 1 item to order.";


    if( is_array($error) )
   {

     echo "An error occurred while processing your order.";
     echo "<br>\n";
     echo "Please check the following error messages carefully, then click back in your browser.";
     echo "<br>\n";

     while(list($key, $val) = each($error))
    {
    echo $val;
    echo "<br>\n";
    }

   //stop everything as we have errors and should not continue
   exit();

   }


  //we do not need the rest of the form fields as we can just calculate them from the whole numbers
  if( !empty($_POST["qtyA"]) )
  {
  $qtyA = $_POST["qtyA"];
  $totalA = $qtyA * 1.25;
  }
  else
  {
  $qtyA = 0;
  $totalA = 0;
  }

  if( !empty($_POST["qtyB"]) )
  {
    $qtyB = $_POST["qtyB"];
    $totalB = $qtyB * 2.35;
  }
    else
  {
    $qtyB = 0;
    $totalB = 0;
   }

  if( !empty($_POST["qtyC"]) )
   {
   $qtyC = $_POST["qtyC"];
   $totalC = $qtyC * 3.45;
   }
    else
   {
   $qtyC = 0;
   $totalC = 0;
   }

  $GrandTotal = $totalA + $totalB + $totalC;


   //we can store the order in a database as well

   $link = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
   if (!$link)
    {
    echo "Could not connect: " . mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
     mysql_select_db('admin');

     $query  = "INSERT INTO order_queue
         (  Name ,   Email ,   OtherInfo ,   qtyA ,
            totalA ,   qtyB ,   totalB ,   qtyC ,   totalC ,   GrandTotal )";
     $query .= " VALUES
         ('$Name', '$Email', '$OtherInfo', '$qtyA',
          '$totalA', '$qtyB', '$totalB', '$qtyC', '$totalC', '$GrandTotal')";
    //echo $query . "<br>\n";

  $result = mysql_query($query);
  mysql_free_result($result);
  mysql_close($link);
 }
?>
```

Order form

```
<form method="POST" action="submitted.php" onsubmit="return Validate(this)" name="ofrm">
<p>Please tell us who you are (<font color="#FF0000">red</font> denotes required information):</p>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="550" id="table1">
<tr>
<td width="340" align="right"><font color="#FF0000">Name</font></td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" name="Name" size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="340" align="right"><font color="#FF0000">Email</font> 
(Your confirmation will be sent here): </td>
<td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="200"><input type="text" name="Email" size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
.......//more here
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subButton" tabindex="50">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="resetButton" tabindex="50">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I just want to make this work to insert in the database. Should I put it on the same page as the form, the **action=" "**, or where?

**EDIT** the form action is now *submitted.php* I put the php script there. it's giving me this error:

```
\n"; echo "Please check the following error messages carefully, then click back in your browser."; echo "
\n"; while(list($key, $val) = each($error)) { echo $val; echo "
\n"; } //stop everything as we have errors and should not continue exit(); } //we do not need the rest of the form fields as we can just calculate them from the whole numbers if( !empty($_POST["qtyA"]) ) { $qtyA = $_POST["qtyA"]; $totalA = $qtyA * 1.25; } else { $qtyA = 0; $totalA = 0; } if( !empty($_POST["qtyB"]) ) { $qtyB = $_POST["qtyB"]; $totalB = $qtyB * 2.35; } else { $qtyB = 0; $totalB = 0; } if( !empty($_POST["qtyC"]) ) { $qtyC = $_POST["qtyC"]; $totalC = $qtyC * 3.45; } else { $qtyC = 0; $totalC = 0; } $GrandTotal = $totalA + $totalB + $totalC; //we can store the order in a database as well $link = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password'); if (!$link) { echo "Could not connect: " . mysql_error(); } else { mysql_select_db('admin'); $query = "INSERT INTO order_queue ( Name , Email , OtherInfo , qtyA , totalA , qtyB , totalB , qtyC , totalC , GrandTotal )"; $query .= " VALUES ('$Name', '$Email', '$OtherInfo', '$qtyA', '$totalA', '$qtyB', '$totalB', '$qtyC', '$totalC', '$GrandTotal')"; //echo $query . "
\n"; $result = mysql_query($query); mysql_free_result($result); mysql_close($link); } ?>
```

Comment: *After clicking the submit button the action for that leads to submitted.html.* Your form shouldn't submit to a html document. it shoud submit to the php script which will handle the `POST`'ed data

Comment: @MichaelColeman So should I paste the php script on let's say submitted.php?

Comment: @MichaelColeman it's now sumitting to submitted.php I put the php code there and it's giving me long errors. i'll edit my post

Comment: Can you provide the HTML containing your form? thanks

Comment: and whats the filename of the php script you have given?

Comment: @MichaelColeman edited. orfm.php contains the form and included javascript. action now has ="submitted.php" I put the php script there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to make a judgement without seeing the markup/html side but here are a few pointers:

- You can submit the page to itself using `htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` in the action attribute on the  tag or to another page `action="submitted.php"`
- Ensure that the input area `name=` attribute names are matching case. If you have `$_POST["test"]` in the scripting after the post then the `<input name="test"` should be the same and not `<input name="Test"`
- If you cannot debug using the IDE then add `echo "1"; echo "2"; echo "3";` in sequence as the script is executed to see where the numbering debug stops. That would be the best place to start troubleshooting.

> ```
>   echo "1";
>   if( empty($_POST["Name"]) )
>   {
>      echo "2";
>      $error["name"] = "Name is required.";
>      $Name = "";
>   }
>   else
>   {
>      echo "3";
>      $Name = $_POST["Name"];
>      echo "4";
>    }
> ```

Not the best example but you get the idea. I usually do this with a large script I try and make sense of.

- Before executing the `INSERT` echo it as text to see if all the variable contain data. You should also output the database error message using `mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());`. Please try and use `PDO` or `mysqli_query` instead.
- Ensure the Javascript validation is not blocking the submit. remove the validation and test the script to see if it submits. If it does then the problem lies on the client side code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: as much as i want to post everything here, it does not permit too much code to post. :( i'll read this pointers of yours thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer yu are loking for, but a few things PHP Beginners should know

- Your code contains some deprecated components [magic_quotes](http://php.net/get_magic_quotes_gpc) [addslashes](http://php.net/addslashes) [mysql*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)
- Your code lacks [input validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet)
- Your code lacks [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Everything like HTML, CSS, Business logic, Presentation Logic are in a single file
- Start using a good IDE like [Komodo](http://komodoide.com/) [PDT](http://eclipse.org/pdt)
- Use a good debugging tool like XDebug
- Finally, start using a good framework like Zend, CakePHP CodeIgniter Symphony or any one of the thousands out there. Almost all frameworks include Form-to-Database in their Getting Started guide